# hyperlink <a> title remove using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to remove the  tag title using XSLT. But it`s not removing. Can one can recommdate solution for remove anchor title.

> XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RichText xmlns="uuid:e25b1476-ce87-4a67-a22b-b82a752810e0">
  <Content>
    <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google Title">
      Hyperlink
    </a>
  </Content>
</RichText>
```

XSLT File:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
    <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
    <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RichText xmlns="uuid:e25b1476-ce87-4a67-a22b-b82a752810e0">
  <Content>
    <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://www.google.com">
      Hyperlink
    </a>
  </Content>
</RichText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns="uuid:e25b1476-ce87-4a67-a22b-b82a752810e0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a/@title"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
You may also do using "xpath-default-namespace".
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [identity transformation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#copying), you need a rule for that attribute with an empty template.

This input

```
<RichText xmlns="uuid:e25b1476-ce87-4a67-a22b-b82a752810e0">
  <Content>
    <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google Title">
      Hyperlink
    </a>
  </Content>
</RichText>
```

With this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:a/@title"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<RichText xmlns="uuid:e25b1476-ce87-4a67-a22b-b82a752810e0">
  <Content>
    <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://www.google.com">
      Hyperlink
    </a>
  </Content>
</RichText>
```

**Note**: look at the use of namespaces.